# Go - Ratios of its elements that are positive, negative, and zero number in a slice

Tags: go

I wanna show the ratios of its elements that are positive, negative, and zero in a slice. I need the ratios in float32. This is my code:

```
arr := []int32{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}

var negativeNumber, positiveNumber, zeroNumber, totalNumber int32
var negativeRatio, positiveRatio, zeroRatio float32

for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
    totalNumber += 1
}

for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
    if arr[i] < 0 {
        negativeNumber += 1
    } else if arr[i] == 0 {
        zeroNumber += 1
    } else if arr[i] > 0 {
        positiveNumber += 1
    }
}

negativeRatio = float32(negativeNumber / totalNumber)
zeroRatio = float32(zeroNumber / totalNumber)
positiveRatio = float32(positiveNumber / totalNumber)

fmt.Printf("total number: %d\n", totalNumber)

fmt.Printf("positive number: %d\n", positiveNumber)
fmt.Printf("negative number: %d\n", negativeNumber)
fmt.Printf("zero number: %d\n", zeroNumber)

fmt.Printf("positive ratio: %f\n", positiveRatio)
fmt.Printf("negative ratio: %f\n", negativeRatio)
fmt.Printf("zero ratio: %f\n", zeroRatio)
```

But, when I print the variables, I get the positive, negative, and zero numbers right but wrong ratio. Here is the output:

```
total number: 5
positive number: 2
negative number: 2
zero number: 1
positive ratio: 0.000000
negative ratio: 0.000000
zero ratio: 0.000000
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: change to this `negativeRatio = float32(negativeNumber) / float32(totalNumber)
 zeroRatio = float32(zeroNumber) / float32(totalNumber)
 positiveRatio = float32(positiveNumber) / float32(totalNumber)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using integer division instead of floating point division, which discards the remainder and returns the integer part of the division result only.

Since `negativeNumber` and `totalNumber` are both of type `int32`, `negativeNumber / totalNumber` performs integer division, which performs the division and returns the floor of the result (which is 0). When you then cast it to a `float32` with `float32(negativeNumber / totalNumber)`, you get `0.0`, which is expected.

In order to use floating point division, one of the operands must be a floating point type. To do this, you can use: `float32(negativeNumber) / totalNumber`